# vbscript auto form submition failed

Tags: vbscript

Hi I have the following vb script that opens a Program, then clicks an ok button on a pop up message then enters a form with server name, user name and password and then clicks submit. The script works well as i have it running as a scheduled logon script.

However if the user opens another window as this script is running then the script fails. I need o make the script a bit more intelligent by focusing on the correct window. Please help.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\SNS EVO ShareBrowser\Client\evo ShareBrowser.exe""")
WScript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "abc"
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
objShell.SendKeys "user"
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
objShell.SendKeys "password"
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
wscript.Quit
```

Comment: You basically want to perform the actions even if the application is not in focus?

Comment: Use [`AppActivate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek(v=vs.84).aspx), or better yet use a proper GUI automation tool like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).